# Расширение сохраняемого файла или синтаксис по умолчанию в Sublime text 3

Tags: файлы, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, синтаксис, markdown

можно ли поменять расширение сохраняемого файла на .txt по умолчанию, кстати даже если выбираю, .txt файл сохраняется без расширения (хотелось бы и об этом узнать как исправить).

По поиску в интернете, показалось что нельзя, тогда если нет, я установил Markdown Editing и думал, может можно как нибудь сделать стандартным синтаксисом при создание нового файла, Markdown и после этого, сделать так чтобы сохранялся Markdown в .txt

Вот такой вопрос, если есть способ буду признателен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text предлагает расширение файла в зависимости от выбранной, на момент сохранения, подсветки синтаксиса.
Погуглил, как можно задать какую-то конкретную подсветку синтаксиса по умолчанию, нашел только через отдельный плагин [Default File Type](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Default%20File%20Type)

Вот ссылка на рекомендацию:
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/any-way-to-change-the-default-syntax-from-plaintext/12170

Попробуйте, может это то, что Вы ищете.